# Unable to sort view based on search index by taxonomy weight

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, search

I have a search index created using search api and I have a view created based on the search index. I have a taxonomy term field called subscription which is indexed. I need to sort my view based on the subscription field and it should be based on the taxonomy term weight and not by the term name. I am able to add the subscription field in my sort criteria but it doesn't seem to be working the way it is expected.

I referred to multiple links but those seem to work only for views based on content and not based on search index.

How do I sort the view(based on Search index) by taxonomy term weight?

Comment: Did you look at this [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1213506) ?

Comment: That seems to be related to Apache Solr and I am using drupal search api for creating my view.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have figured this out yet, but I found the solution to this, so I'll post it here in case anyone else comes along this page.

If you go to your search index and go to the Fields tab, you'll see at the very bottom there is text that says "Add related fields". It took a while for me to see this there, since it's kind of inconspicuous and under the form submit button. But if you click that and select your taxonomy, it will add the set of taxonomy fields to the available list of fields to index. Check "Weight", then that will be available in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will try to explain my approach.

I didn't use Sorts module. The steps I took are the following:

I made a custom field with this hook:
    hook_entity_property_info_alter() in a separate module. In my getter
    callback I found the weight of the term I wanted and returned it as
    INTEGER like: return intval($weight); I ticked the newly created
    field to index it and chose Integer as format. Re-indexed the index.
    Lastly, in my view in Sort criteria I chose Sort ascending and
    voila!!

Comment: Sounds interesting. I will give it a try and get back to you. Thanks @geodoo

Comment: If you need any help with this I can provide some code. Feel free to ask! You are welcome @Bhuvana